# How to count sum on the day of entering record

Tags: c#, linq

**Here im fetching record By using datetime.But i want that day Whole informatio Like Sum**

**Example**

```
ID    Name          Date            Amount
1     Samsung        1/1/2016        3000
2      LG            1/1/2016        6000
3      Videocon      2/2/2015        200
4     Philips        2/2/2015        1500
5     Sony            3/5/2015       15000
```

If I `Select` date Like `1/1/2016` its should Give me complete `Result` along with `total --> 9000` & also its mentioned as `Samsung-->3000` `Lg--->6000` `Total 9000`
Here I have Some Code

```
   public JsonResult Dif(int Date=0, int Month=0, int Year=0, int HH = 0, int MM = 0, int Ss = 0){
 DateTime ss = new DateTime(Year, Month, Date, HH, MM, Ss);
var x = (from n in db.Employees where (n.DataofJoin == ss) select n);
  return new JsonResult {Data=x, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var total = db.Employees.Where(x=>x.Date == yourDate).Select(y=> y.Amount).Sum();
```

If you want to receive the total for the Phone model per date.

```
var result = db.Employees.Where(x=>x.Date == yourDate).
             GroupBy(x=>x.Name, y=> y.Amount, 
                     (x, y) => new { PhoneName = x, TotalAmount = y.Sum()).ToList();
```

This will return you List of Phone per specific date and total amount about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var total = (from n in db.Employees where (n.DataofJoin == ss) select n.Amount).Sum();
```

Edit (thanks Mrinal for correction):
you may try following syntax:

```
//Get total
var total = employees.Where(ef => ef.DataofJoin == yourDate).Select(f => f.Amount).Sum();
//get list with total
var result = employees.Where(e => ef.DataofJoin == yourDate).ToList();
//Add object for total amount
result.Add(new employee { name = "Total", Amount = total });
```

Comment: its giving me as total amount but i need complete information like Id=1,Name=Samsung,Lg & total as ..Like that

Comment: You cannot get objects and total sum in one expression. You need two different statements

Comment: You are sure this is what your question suggest, then its fairly confusing and misleading

Comment: He wants list of objects with sum of amounts.

Comment: @kashi_rock Where are you fetching that in the tabulated format as suggested in the question, you are firing separate queries, better write a foreach loop

Comment: What do you mean by tabulated format. Question is to get list of product, its amount and total amount for all products for said date i.e. 1/1/2016.

Comment: Anyway the idea was to get it in a single call, which is feasible using the combination of GroupBy and SelectMany